# Could SQL Binary Tree organization be more efficient when iterating on a large table?

Tags: sql

I have a transaction table that holds over 2 million records. I thought if I established another column that is called 'Parent ID' and linked the next node inserted (through a trigger) to the previous node, it would make it more efficient.

Would creating a binary tree and using Self-Join queries to search for the record be more efficient?

How do organization cope when having tables with millions of records? Do they come up with a data structure that reduces the search time?

Are there articles that describe the whole sql modification and search that describe how to achieve that?

> Update

This is my table

```
PaymentTransaction
Id
Amount
UserID
TimeCreated
```

If I add another column

```
PaymentTransaction
Id
Amount
UserID
TimeCreated
ParentID
```

then I will be able to establish parent-child relationship. That would enable me to establish a binary tree. A binary tree is faster than sequential search right? since it 'flattens' the data structure and by doing so eliminates unnecessary iterations.

Here is an example of an implementation of Binary tree in SQL.

[Binary Tree link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/binary-trees-in-sql/)

How more efficient is its implementation on a large table?

Comment: It really depends what your goals are. Quick write times? Quick read times? Ability to write simple queries? The technology you're using will also matter; different database systems are good at different things. There are absolute mountains of articles/books on this topic.

Comment: Can't really answer without understanding the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: And some better understanding of your schema.  When I think of a transactions table, I don't normally think of one transaction being a "parent" of another

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're just describing creating an index. Almost all database systems can do that for you automatically, and with better performance than trying to do it yourself.